# How can I select an image without giving boundBy value in swift Automation

Tags: ios, swift, testing, automated-tests, image-gallery

I used below code it worked but I don't want to give a specific value its should randomly pick image or Video from the gallery

```
app.collectionViews.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 2).children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.tap()
```

Is there any other way to pick random images from the Gallery?

Comment: Is this inside an XCUITest? You might want to be more specific about that in your question title to help people searching for problems. If it is in a test, are you sure you want something random in a test?

Comment: @alexkent Yes This in XCUITest only, Yes am sure I want to select random Images/Videos